Does the shape of the container affect dough rise?
I'm making focaccia but this probably applies to any bread/dough.
Does resting the dough in a deep bowl give a better/worse rise than a flatter dish (e.g: a tray dish you'd use to actually bake the thing).
I have this deep, V-shaped baking bowl with steep sides. My theory is that a deeper container allows for a better rise since there's more dough in the vertical axis. The walls also might support the dough better.

a narrower container would have walls to cling to, but there would be more weight per unit area.  Some of the really wet 'no knead' doughs rely on this to keep it from climbing out of the containers as it will collapse back on itself, but I have no idea where that inflection point is

The purpose of the first rise is to let the yeast fully activate, gluten to develop and expand the dough as the yeast ferments sugars. If you do it long and slow in the fridge you'll get some flavor development as well.
There's very little difference in using a bowl over a tray, all those processes work regardless. You may see a bit less lift in a bowl over a tray because there's more weight on top of the dough at the bottom of the bowl, however once you move it to your baking dish or tray it's going to bounce back so you won't notice a difference in the end.
You want to handle focaccia, ciabatta and other very high hydration doughs as little as you can because you are trying to get as light a structure as possible. Proofing focaccia in a bowl and then transferring it to a dish just knocks air out of it,  although you'll get most of it back in the second rise. You can get maximum air by proofing it in the dish or pan it's going to be baked in, and save yourself the hassle of moving it at the same time.
With doughs you have to shape you're going to lose some air, some need to be worked a bit before the second rise to ensure consistency, in either case bowl or tray makes no difference.

+1 for going straight to an important and counterintuitive point: we are not rising dough because we want it to rise! The rising is just a side effect which is conveniently used as a marker for how far the desired processes have advanced, so it's not constructive to worry about having it go higher or not.

@rumtscho what about breads like focaccia where an airy structure is desired? Or is that still mostly down to the 2nd rise?

Re: proofing on the dish/pan you are going to bake on, would you do this with a single rise recipe? Pertsonally I feel it would lead to a thin layer of dough that was hard to work compared with dough gently poured from a bowl?
